# Access x value on axis d3

Tags: d3.js

I think this is a simple question but I'm not getting it. I have the following code for the x-axis of my bar chart, and I'm trying to access the x-value when the corresponding bar is clicked. I've tried selecting xAxis, x, and .domain, but I'm getting null values.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(['191','192','255','902'])
    .rangeRoundBands([margin,w-margin], .1)

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(3, 0)


svg.selectAll(".series")
   .data(ratiodata)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .classed("series",true)
   .style("fill","url(#gradient)")
   .selectAll("rect").data(Object)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("x",function(d,i) { return x(x.domain()[i])})
   .attr("y",function(d) { return y(d.y0)})
   .attr("height",function(d) { return y(0)-y(d.size)})
   .attr("width",x.rangeBand())
   .on("click", function(d,i) {
         //Clicking on the bar currently displays elements from another dataset.//
         //Ratiodata is only used for displaying the bars//
      });
```

Comment: I am assuming that you are drawing one bar per datum point. In that case, the click handler will be passed the data associated with the bar already and you do not need to `invert` the axis. Could you show how you are handling the click event?

Comment: Sure, I've just edited the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value in the same way in that you're setting it to start with:

```
.on("click", function(d, i) {
  console.log(x.domain()[i]);
});
```